# IO on file descriptors

Tags: c++, linux, file, ifstream, file-descriptor

I just ran into the following behavior and would like to know the reasons behind it:

Assume a simplified program like that

```
...
{
  std::ifstream in(argv[1]);
  assert(in.good());
  while (std::getline(in, line)) {
   // Area 1
  }
  in.close();
}
{
  std::ifstream in(argv[1]);
  assert(in.good());
  while (std::getline(in, line)) {
   // Area 2
  }
  in.close();
}
```

if such a program is call like that:

```
./myProg xxx
```

**Both**, Area 1 and Area 2 will be entered n times where n is the number of lines in xxx.

However, I if called like that (using bash):

```
./myProg <(head -n 100 xxx)
```

**Area 1** will be entered **100** times and **Area 2** will be entered **0** times. Both assertions (in.good()) do pass. Appearently the second one passes a file descriptor (something like /dev/fd/63 if I print the argument) instead of an actual file and this thing can be opened for reading once - but when opened twice, it appears to be empty for the second call.

I wonder what the reason behind that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `head` process is executed once by `bash` and has it's output redirected to a pipe which your process can access through that file inode. Your program knows nothing about that `head` command and trying to close and re-open the file won't cause it to be executed again.

It's similar to the situation you would have if your program read from `cin` and you execute it as `head -n 100 xxx | ./myProg`. You wouldn't expect to be able to read the data twice via `cin` in that scenario. This is the same.